# How to return a tuple to frontend from wasm?

Tags: rust, frontend, webassembly, wasm-bindgen, wasm-pack

I'm new to webassembly. I want to create a simple greedy snake game using canvas and `wasm_bindgen`.

My rust code:

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen]
impl CanvasData {
    pub fn index_to_coordinate(&self, index: usize) -> (usize, usize) {
      (index % self.cell_count, index / self.cell_count)
    }
}
```

`CanvasData` is a struct that saves data of the canvas, `cell_count` attribute is `usize` type, it represents the number of horizontal and vertical grids on the square canvas. Here I treat all the grids on the canvas as a one-dimensional array from left to right and from top to bottom. The purpose of this method is to map the array index to x, y coordinates. I want to return a tuple and call it in the front end as follows:

```js
const [x, y] = canvasData.index_to_coordinate(100)
```

However, an error occurred during building.

Build script:

```
wasm-pack build -t web
```

Error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `(usize, usize): IntoWasmAbi` is not satisfied
[0]   --> src\lib.rs:16:1
[0]    |
[0] 16 | #[wasm_bindgen]
[0]    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `IntoWasmAbi` is not implemented for `(usize, usize)`
[0]    |
[0]    = help: the trait `IntoWasmAbi` is implemented for `()`
[0]    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `ReturnWasmAbi` for `(usize, usize)`
[0]    = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `wasm_bindgen::prelude::__wasm_bindgen_class_marker` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

How to reslove this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe `tuples` are not currently allowed because `wasm-bindgen` is waiting for [tuples to be added to javascript](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-record-tuple) so there isnt future inconstancy/breakage between rust and js. There is an open issue on `wasm-bindgen` asking for `tuples` and fixed-sized arrays [here](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/issues/122).

For now, the best approach is probably to just create a tuple struct.

```
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub struct Coordinates(pub usize, pub usize);
```

Then you can deconstruct it in javascript the same way.

```js
const [x, y] = canvasData.index_to_coordinate(100)
```

Or use a struct with named fields and deconstruct the object

```
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub struct Coordinates{
   pub x: usize,
   pub y: usize
}
```

```js
const {x, y} = canvasData.index_to_coordinate(100)
```