How can I return a tuple to javascript from wasm where elements have non Copy/Clone traits?
I have a problem where I need to return a tuple from a wasm function as the following:
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn channel() -> (futures::channel::mpsc::Sender<i32>, futures::channel::mpsc::Receiver<i32>) {
    let (mut tx, mut rx) = futures::channel::mpsc::channel(32);
    return (tx, rx)
}

(I need to return the sender and receiver with separate ownership)
It is not possible to return a tuple as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75064902/14923227
However, the provided workaround does not work for me since Receiver does not implement Copy or Clone trait.
I have tried solving this by returning a Struct Pair instead with getter methods for sender and receiver:
#[wasm_bindgen]
struct WrappedReceiver {
    receiver: futures::channel::mpsc::Receiver<i32>
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub struct Pair {
    sender: futures::channel::mpsc::Sender<i32>,
    receiver: WrappedReceiver
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
impl Pair {
    #[wasm_bindgen(getter)]
    pub fn receiver(&self) -> WrappedReceiver {
        return self.receiver
    }
}

This compiles with the same issue, that WrappedReceiver does not implement Copy trait.
I can however wrap the Receiver in Rc with the following:

#[wasm_bindgen]
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct WrappedSender(futures::channel::mpsc::Sender<i32>);

#[wasm_bindgen]
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct WrappedReceiver(Rc<futures::channel::mpsc::Receiver<i32>>);

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub struct Pair {
    #[wasm_bindgen(getter_with_clone)]
    pub sender: WrappedSender,
    #[wasm_bindgen(getter_with_clone)]
    pub receiver: WrappedReceiver
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
impl Pair {
    #[wasm_bindgen(constructor)]
    pub fn new() -> Pair {
        let (mut tx, mut rx) = futures::channel::mpsc::channel(32);
        Pair {
            sender: WrappedSender(tx),
            receiver: WrappedReceiver(Rc::new(rx))
       }
    }
}

It not works to destruct the Pair in JavaScript with the following:
import * as wasm from './pkg'
const { receiver, sender } = new wasm.Pair()

I have some other place where I need to use the futures::channel::Receiver<i32> with exclusive ownership &mut (ideally I want it to be a futures stream).
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn use_receiever(receiver: &mut WrappedReceiver) {
    let rx: Pin<Box<dyn futures::stream::Stream<Item = i32>>> = receiver.0.boxed_local();
}

This is because I cannot convert WrappedReceiver to a &mut futures::channel::mpsc::Receiver<i32> I think.
playground link
I could use a Rc<RefCell<futures::channel::mpsc::Receiver<i32>>> which would allow me to borrow mutually:
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn use_receiever(receiver: &mut WrappedReceiver) {
    let rx: &mut futures::channel::mpsc::Receiver<i32> = &mut receiver.0.borrow_mut();
}

playground link
This seems to work, but it feels like I am adding to many constructions. I also only want single ownership of futures::channel::mpsc::Receiver<i32>, whereas RefCell is more suitable for multiple ownership?
Ideally I would like WrappedReceiver to be the following:
#[wasm_bindgen]
struct WrappedReceiver {
    receiver: Pin<Box<dyn futures::stream::Stream<Item = i32>>>,
}

Is there a way to achieve this?

Why your use_receiver receives mutable reference of wrapper? can you make it non reference and non mutable? then that block will implicitly becomes the owner and  you can use std::ops::Deref to get rid of wrapper and RC let mut rx: &futures::channel::mpsc::Receiver<i32> = receiver.0.deref();

I need to have a mutable reference to the underlying stream, since it is used in another function with the type argument stream: &mut (impl futures::stream::Stream<Item = i32> + Unpin). I want to the pin the stream to a struct WrappedReceiver (or something that can assigned a variable in JS) and use it to invoke multiple external functions in rust (not simultaneously) from JS.

I tried using std::ops::Deref with an RC which you mention, but I cannot get it to work calling some "external function" since the types differ in mutability: playground link.

Then make it &mut. It is fine, I'm not 100% what your JS code does, if you need a refrence, that is totally fine

It is possible to use Option which has the take method which moves the value out from the option. This makes it possible to temporarily take ownership of Receiver.
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub struct Pair {
    sender: futures::channel::mpsc::Sender<i32>,
    receiver: Option<futures::channel::mpsc::Receiver<i32>>
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
impl Pair {
    #[wasm_bindgen(constructor)]
    pub fn new() -> Pair {
        let (tx, rx) = futures::channel::mpsc::channel(32);
        Pair {
            sender: tx,
            receiver: Some(rx)
       }
    }

    #[wasm_bindgen(getter)]
    pub fn receiver(&mut self) -> WrappedReceiver {
        WrappedReceiver { receiver: self.receiver.take().unwrap().boxed_local() }
    }

    #[wasm_bindgen(getter)]
    pub fn sender(&self) -> WrappedSender {
        WrappedSender { sender: self.sender.clone() }
    }
}

It is then possible to de-structure the object in JS with the following:
const { receiver, sender } = new wasm.Pair()

